# to calculate CDF of a continuous regression

Tags: python-3.x, regression, cdf

I need to calculate a CDF for a regression.I have N observations, I need to reestimate coefficients(beta) in a joint distribution.
Yobs is my observations and Y is calculated by X(matrix of predctors)* array of coefficients(betas)

```
def CDF(beta):
    Y = X.dot(beta)
    sigma = 0
    for n in range(0,N):
       sigma = sigma + (np.square(Yobs[n] - Y[n])) # summation of squarred of residuals
    SSR = sigma / N    # mu (mean or expectation)
    dof = N - P - 1    # degree of freedom
    var = sigma / dof  # the mean square of residuals
    PDF = np.zeros(N)
    CDF = np.zeros(N)  # I want to calculate the F(X < Yobs)
    for n in range (0,N):
       PDF[n] = (1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*var))*np.exp(-SSR/(2*var))  # probability density function
       CDF[n] = integrate.quad(PDF, -np.inf , (Yobs+a))    # CDF
    return CDF
```

Where am I wrong? I think CDF is wrong since I haven't determined the arg, but how can I define? can I simply use?

```
from scipy.stats import norm
def CDF(beta):
    Y = X.dot(beta)
    sigma = 0
    for n in range(0,N):
       sigma = sigma + (np.square(Yobs[n] - Y[n])) # summation of squarred of residuals
    SSR = sigma / N    # mu (mean or expectation)
    dof = N - P - 1    # degree of freedom
    var = sigma / dof  # the mean square of residuals
    CDF = np.zeros(N)
    for n in range(0,N):           # I want to calculate the F(X < Yobs)
        CDF[n] = norm.cdf(Yobs[n],SSR,var)
    return CDF
```

Comment: What isn't working, are you getting an error or is the code working but the result is incorrect? I'm assuming this is part of a larger script where X is defined outside the function, is that so?

Comment: Yes, it works, but I am not sure about the result. Do you think am I right?  P.S.  correct, X matrix has been defined outside the function.

Comment: (FYI, the tag [tag:pdf] is for Adobe's Portable Document Format, and not related to your question.)